# Public and private classes

Tags: encryption

I have a a robot program in Android Studio written in Java with certain lines designated as a public or private class. I have to submit a form with a section for labeled "key algorithms", but it doesn't specify what exactly that means, and I am wondering if those qualify.

This is a segment of the code, to show you an example of what I mean:

```
private org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.HardwareIndibot robot = new HardwareIndibot();
```

Are these classes encryption keys or are they just algorithms?

Comment: We need a lot more context.  Public and private classes usually refers to language-specific constructs that prevent access to data from certain parts of your program, which is not at all related to public-key cryptography.  What is this form, and what does is actually say?

Comment: i am very new to programming and don't know what half of what anything means. please bear with me.

Comment: public/private classes and encryption algorithms are completely unrelated. Don't hold any presumptions and consult the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Public and private classes are just concepts inside a programming language which help with design by distinguishing between internal implementations (i.e. private) which can change all the time and public API which should be mostly constant. They are not a security concept but a design concept. It is also possible to bypass these "restrictions" depending on the programming language, for example with [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) in Java.